# How to get select data into Whatsapp button?

Tags: wordpress, whatsapp, contact-form-7

This is a simple form (contact form 7) is it possible to get select value in whatsapp button ?

for example please check [image](http://prntscr.com/qj5ibw)

Currently using this button

```
whatsapp://send?text=Hello! I Need pickup and drop for date &phone=+910000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, if you are using AJAX to submit your form, you need to hook the cf7 plugin filter, 'wpcf7_mail_sent' which is fired once your form is validated and the notification mail is sent.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_sent','get_form_data');
function get_form_data($form){
  //the submitted data is available in the $_POST session variable.
  $phone_number = $_POST['phone-number']; //where 'phone-number' is your field name.
}
```

you can then store these values into a [transient](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-transients-in-wordpress) to retrieve for building your whatsapp button.

alternatively, if you are submitting your form using a 'POST' request, then you can simply add this code to your action page,

```
if(isset($_POST['phone-number'])){
  $phone_number= $_POST[phone-number];
  // and then continnue to build your whatsapp button.
}
```